# Load height of banner responsive before of content below

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, banner

I'm developing a banner responsive website, however I don't know the height, when the page loads the content below the banner loads first than the banner. How do I load height of banner first?

By "banner" I mean the big image in the background.
My site: http://skillsoft.com.br/skill2015

This is the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/r6vn1ruq2tz759c/ba26970d.png

html code

```
<figure class="hero-banner">
    <img class="hero-banner__image" src="assets/img/banners/home.jpg" alt="Homem saltando entre montanhas rochosas, com um ceú azul sem nuvens" width="1920" height="700">
    <figcaption class="hero-banner__description">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Melhore seus resultados<br>Amplie horizontes</h2>
            <h1>Sistemas de gestão empresarial</h1>
        </div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

css code

```
.hero-banner {

    &__image {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    &__description {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi could you please post your code here on stack overflow with some more information about what isn't working?  What you are asking is not clear.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, sorry for my english :P

Comment: No problem - it will be easier to understand if we can see the code you're having trouble with and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: If the banner you're referring to is the hero image, then the height is already set in the HTML (`height="700"`). The image also comes first in the HTML, so it begins to load before the content which comes further down in the code. Maybe you could provide a better explanation along with the code.

Comment: I improved my question, I hope that help it.